# Row in CSS Grid should take up remaining space

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a very simple CSS grid with just two rows: a `header` and a `div`. I want the second row to take up all remaining view port height. Here's a repro:

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

header {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>IMG + Some header text</h1>
</header>

<div class="content">
  Here will be dynamic content (a grid on its own).
  Should take all the remaining height.
</div>
```

This uses way too much space for the `header`. I want it to take up at most as much space as needed for its content not to overflow.

How can I do this?

I'm interested about any spec-based solution, though practically I would like to be able to use it at least in Chrome (or Firefox) latest stable build.

Comment: `spec-based solution` - any specific version/draft you desire?

Comment: No, not really, as long as it's finalized. Just no vendor-specific experiments is what I meant.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Specify auto sizing for the header row and `1fr` to allocate all the remaining space to the content row.

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

header {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>IMG + Some header text</h1>
</header>

<div class="content">
  Here will be dynamic content (a grid on its own).
  Should take all the remaining height.
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to make use of `grid-template-rows` which is used to declare the area occupied by each row
where

- **minmax(10px, auto)** defines that the minimum height is 10px and maximum height can be expanded as the content increases dynamically for the **header row**.
- 1fr is 1 fraction of the entire remaining space for **content row**.

You can also make use of ***auto*** instead of ***minmax*** if you *don't want to set a minimum height*.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(1px, auto) 1fr;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

header {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>IMG + Some header text</h1>
</header>

<div class="content">
  Here will be dynamic content (a grid on its own). Should take all the remaining height.
</div>
```